# Javascript node list looping not working as it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodelist

I believe that my initial question was not clear as to what I was trying to accomplish. I was newer and I was trying to figure out how exactly I was to use a javascript loop in order to loop through certain elements to remove them. It's a simple task, but, as a beginner, you're not going to really necessarily know what it is that you need to do without studying the documentation.

I have provided a sample finished code that demonstrates removing the different paragraph items using e.target. I was not able to get e.target.innerHTML to work, however, e.target worked just fine.

```js
let para = document.querySelectorAll('p'); 
for (i = 0; i < para.length; i++){
para[i].addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
let target = e.target; 
target.style.display="none"; }, false); 
}
```

```html
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<p>Para 3</p>
```

Comment: You should format the question correctly using a code snippet, and simplify it as much as possible. Code is too long to analyse this way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please read this, and edit your question

Comment: +1 to what @PabloCG said. Also please specify what the desired behavior is and how it is behaving now.

I uploaded your code to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ac3L5m7/) so you may have a reference on how to upload your snippet here. When editing your question, press **`Ctrl + M`** to add a snippet to it and make sure that it runs as it does in your local machine. It seems to have some syntax problems (like missing `@` in CSS keyframes declaration). Make sure to fix those, too.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if it's short enough for you guys now please.

Comment: I fixed the @ in the keyframes declaration. I'll review my CSS later in the day. My focus right now is on why the JS isn't working as it should. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @PabloCG I updated the code in the form of a snippet, and, it should explain what I was trying to do earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Yayyy!!!! After a fun breakthrough session, I've figured out what the heck that I was doing wrong. I misunderstood where to put the index. I also misunderstood how to apply the Switch statement. I've found a means to apply the Switch statements and then let them go through until the end so that way the carousel that I'm working won't be broken. Finally.

As far as the broken code, it just took a lot of experimenting, and, sometimes, I'm not honestly sure why it wasn't working. But, I did it from scratch. I figured that something previously in the code was making it not work and I took it out and added newer code in and it works. I'll definitely clean up my CSS now.